# Laravel 5.5 как связать вывод таблицы

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Есть 2 таблицы: 1 это книги 2 это авторы. У книг есть поле authors_id которое содержит номер id автора написавшего книгу. У меня несколько вопросов. 1) Как правильно в Laravel вывести на страницу книг автора который написал книгу????Я вывел книги но не понимаю как вывести автора

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Books;

class BooksController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
        $booksList = Books::All();

        return view('books')->with('booksList', $booksList);
    }
}
```

Вопрос 2: Каким образом мне сделать так , чтобы я мог несколько авторов привязывать к одной книги(2 автора могли писать одну книгу).

Comment: 1. Использовать связь [Один-ко-многим](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). 2. Иcпользовать связь [Многие-ко-многим](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: @u_mulder Method [belongsToMany] does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как у одного автора может быть множество книг, а так же у одной книги может быть множество авторов, такая связь называется "многие ко многим" и организовывается через вспомогательную таблицу.

Если хотите сделать все как положено, вам необходимо удалить из таблицы books поле authors_id. 
Далее создать новую таблицу book_author с полями book_id и author_id

Модели Author добавить метод books

```
class Author extends Model {
    //Связь многие ко многим
    public function books() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'book_author'); //второй аргумент имя связной таблицы
    }
}
```

Модели Book добавить метод authors

```
class Book extends Model {
    //Связь многие ко многим
    public function authors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author', 'book_author'); //второй аргумент имя связной таблицы
    }
}
```

Связи моделей готовы.

При добавлении в базу новой книги:

```
$book = new Book(['title' => 'Название книги', 'publisher' => 'Имя издателя']);
```

Добавляем произвольное количество авторов (id):

```
$book->authors()->attach(1, 2, 10, 40);
```

Так же советую освоить методы detach и sync.

Чтение информации из базы.
Получаем коллекцию моделей Book, загружая сразу связные модели Autor

```
$books = Book::with('autors')->get();
```

Далее обращаясь к свойству autors, каждой модели можно получить коллекцию моделей авторов книги.

```
foreach $books as $book {
    foreach ($book->autors as $author) {
        dump($author);
    }
}
```

Можно сделать обратную операцию. Получить авторов и к каждому автору загрузить связную модель книг.

```
$authors = Author::with('books')->get();

foreach $authors as $author {
    foreach ($author->books as $book) {
        dump($book);
    }
}
```